# Как сделать распознавание речи + графический интерфейс (Python 3x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Я делаю голосового помощника на комп, и я добавил к нему графический интерфейс на tkinter (все такие командная строка как-то не комильфо) но проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на кнопку прослушки, окно зависает, отвиснет только когда прослушка закончится. Вот функция прослушки:

```
try:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='ru-RU')
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print('Ошибка...')
except sr.RequestError:
    print('ОШИБКА! Вы не подключены к интернету!\nПроверьте подключение!') 
anwser = query.lower()
print(anwser)
```

Когда человек нажимал на кнопку, вызывалась функция, в которой находится этот код, и все зависало, заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ваше окно в tkiner является циклом, за счёт этого оно обновляется и реагирует на действия пользователя. Знаете что такое поток? Один поток может выполнять только одно действие (или список действий) по порядку. Когда вы запускаете прослушивание речи ваш основной поток занимается записью речи и больше не может обновлять ваше окно. Из за этого ОС считает, что программа зависла. Когда прослушивание завершается - поток свободен и снова начинает обновлять окно. Просто вынесите ваше прослушивание в отдельный поток и ошибка исправится. Потоки в Python https://python-scripts.com/threading

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import sys
from io import BytesIO
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, messagebox
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
from speech_recognition import  (Recognizer, Microphone, UnknownValueError, RequestError)


def internet_status():
    try:
        requests.get('http://216.58.192.142', timeout=1)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        Tk().withdraw()
        result = messagebox.showinfo(title="Сообщение об ошибке!", message="""Для работы приложения,\nтребуется доступ к сети Интернет.""")

        print(result)
        if result == "ok":
            sys.exit()
internet_status()


class VoiceAssistant(Tk):
    error = None
    status = ''
    command = ''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.recognizer = Recognizer()

        self.user_interface()

    def user_interface(self):
        self.geometry("502x240+400+200")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.title("Голосовой ассистент")

        self.background_image = Label(self)
        self.background_image.pack()

        self.button_activate = Button(self, text="Активировать помощника")
        self.button_activate.pack(side="left")
        self.button_activate.config(font=("Times", 15, "bold"), fg="green")
        self.button_activate.configure(command=self.assistant)

        self.label_status = Label(self)
        self.label_status.pack(side="right")
        self.label_status.configure(font=("Times", 18, "bold"), fg="blue")
        self.label_status.config(padx=50, pady=5)

        image = self.get_image
        self.set_background_image(image)

        icon = self.get_icon
        self.set_icon(icon)

    @property
    def get_image(self):
        url = "https://recsquare.ru/upload/medialibrary/4c2/4c2f6c06ef7d87b3d4740109ce5c52a8.jpg"
        content = requests.get(url).content
        pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
        pil_image.thumbnail((500, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image, master=self.background_image)
        return image

    @property
    def get_icon(self):
        url = "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/38/PNG/512/micro_microphone_4764.png"
        content = requests.get(url).content
        pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
        pil_image.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image, master=self)
        return icon

    def set_background_image(self, image):
        self.background_image.configure(image=image)
        self.background_image = image
    def set_icon(self, icon):
        self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, icon)

    def assistant(self):
        self.button_activate.configure(state="disabled")
        self.status = "speak"
        def run():
            try:
                with Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
                    audio = self.recognizer.listen(source)
                self.status = "recognition"
                result = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='ru-RU')
                result = result.lower()
                print(result)
                self.status = "success"
                self.command_handler(result)
            except UnknownValueError:
                self.error = "UnknownValueError"
                print(self.error)
                return
            except RequestError:
                self.error = "RequestError"
                print(self.error)
                return
        self.th = Thread(target=run)
        self.th.start()
        self.status_assistant()

    def status_assistant(self):
        print(self.status)
        if self.error == "UnknownValueError":
            self.button_activate.configure(state="normal")
            self.label_status['text'] = "Не распознано"
            self.error = None
            self.status = ""
            return
        elif self.error == "RequestError":
            self.button_activate.configure(state="normal")
            self.label_status['text'] = "Нет данных!"
            self.error = None
            self.status = ""
            return
        elif self.status == "speak":
            self.label_status['text'] = "Говорите!"
        elif self.status == "recognition":
            self.label_status['text'] = "Распознавание..."
        elif self.status == "success":
            self.label_status['text'] = "Выполняю..."
            self.button_activate.configure(state="normal")
        self.after(300, self.status_assistant)

    def command_handler(self, command):
        print(command)
        if command == "открой блокнот":
            os.system("notepad")
        self.label_status['text'] = "Завершено"
        self.status = ""

def main():
    application = VoiceAssistant()
    application.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```